# How to make jQuery available in ujs response templates for rails 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading an existing (working) app to rails 7 from 6.  I've imported jQuery and UJS like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery' 
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
Rails.start();
```

And then when a link has `data-remote="true"` set it fetches the .js.erb template, just like before.

That template is giving an error though

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

jQuery was previously (before upgrade) available in these templates.  How can I make it available again in Rails 7?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, just make it global in the window.  odd it didn't need it before really.

```
import $ from 'jquery' 
import jquery from 'jquery'

window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery
```